# How i can sort this hash by created of and key ,value pair

Tags: ruby, hash

Hi i am little struggle to make this hash and sort it by created of and key , value pair.

Here is my code

```
 hash_answers = {}
 unless answers.blank?
  answers.each_with_index do |ans ,index|
    voted_up_users = ans.votes_up_by_all_users(ans)
    voted_down_users = ans.votes_down_by_all_users(ans)
    hash_answers[ans.id] = voted_up_users.count -voted_down_users.count #line one
    hash_answers[index+1] = ans.created_at # line 2
  end
end
```

if i have line 1 only in code not line 2 then this below code work fine for me

```
     @answers = hash_answers.sort_by { |key, value| value }.reverse
```

but i also want to sort it by craeted_at

How i can achive this or make hash in another way

Any help will be most appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Could you please describe in more detail what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I don't _really_ understand what you're trying to do, but Hashmaps are unordered collections. You can't sort them.

Comment: Actually, you can sort a hash, but there's not a lot of value in it. A hash maintains its insert order so if you sort an existing hash by its keys and build a new hash from the resulting list, the new hash will remain sorted. It won't be any more efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you can sort on a number of things by creating an array of these things and use that as your sort key:

```
@answers = hash_answers.sort_by { |k, v| [ v[:created_at], v[:count] }
```

This is dependent on having a sortable structure to start with. You're jamming two entirely different things into the same hash. A better approach might be:

```
hash_answers[ans.id] = {
  :id => ans.id,
  :count => voted_up_users.count -voted_down_users.count,
  :created_at => ans.created_at
}
```

You can adjust the order of the elements in the array to sort in the correct order.

Comment: That means you're referencing an array as if it was a hash. Make sure that `v` in the `sort_by` iterator is a Hash as it should be.

Answer (score 1):

```
answers.sort_by do |ans|
  [ans.net_votes, ans.created_at]
end
```

Then in your Answers class

```
def net_votes
  votes_up_by_all_users - votes_down_by_all_users
end
```

You shouldn't have to pass an object to itself as a variable as in `ans.votes_up_by_all_users(ans)`. Objects always know about themselves.